# Android update adapter doesn't work correctly

Tags: android

In this code I have a custom adapter, and after I add new data into `ArrayList` my `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't work.

```
public class ReceiveListFragment extends ListFragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    public ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items;

    private int prevVisibleItem;
    private boolean isFirstTime;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private String config_username;
    private String config_password;
    private ReceivedAdapter adapter;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        db = new DatabaseHandler(G.context);
        config_username = Configuration.getInstance()
                .getString(getActivity(),
                        Configuration.SharedPrefsTypes.USERNAME);

        config_password = Configuration.getInstance()
                .getString(getActivity(),
                        Configuration.SharedPrefsTypes.PASSWORD);

        items = new ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure>();


        getRequestFromServer(0, 10);

        adapter = new ReceivedAdapter(G.context, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Timer smsThread = new Timer();
        GetSMSThread getSMSThread = new GetSMSThread();
        smsThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(getSMSThread, 1, 10000); //(timertask,delay,period)


        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    private String getRequestFromServer(long lastID, int count) {
        String received = "";
        try {
            received = new JsonService(config_username, config_password, lastID, count, G.F_RECEIVE_SMS).request();
            JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(received);

            String mUserID = config_username;
            for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_obj = data_array.getJSONObject(i);

                String mLastID = json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms");
                String mSmsBody = json_obj.getString("sms_body");
                String mSmsNumber = json_obj.getString("sms_number");
                String mSenderName = json_obj.getString("mobile_number");
                String mContactName = json_obj.getString("contact_name");
                String mDate = json_obj.getString("recived_date");

                ReceivedItemStructure item = new ReceivedItemStructure(
                        mLastID,
                        mUserID,
                        mSmsBody,
                        mSmsNumber,
                        mSenderName,
                        mContactName,
                        mDate
                );
                items.add(item);
                //Log.e(" ", "" + mLastID);
            }

            /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return received;
    }


    public long getLastID() {
        return Long.parseLong(items.get(items.size() - 1).getmLastID());
    }

    private void addDataToList(String LastID, String SmsBody, String SmsNumber, String SenderName, String ContactName, String Date) {
        String mLastID      = LastID;
        String mUserID      = config_username;
        String mSmsBody     = SmsBody;
        String mSmsNumber   = SmsNumber;
        String mSenderName  = SenderName;
        String mContactName = ContactName;
        String mDate = Date;
        ReceivedItemStructure item = new ReceivedItemStructure(
                mLastID,
                mUserID,
                mSmsBody,
                mSmsNumber,
                mSenderName,
                mContactName,
                mDate
        );
        items.add(item);
        adapter.update(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class GetSMSThread extends TimerTask {
        private Long lastID;
        private SQLiteDatabase dbHelper;
        private List<ReceiveListFragment> rows;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            lastID = getLastID();
            if (Configuration.getInstance().checkInternetConnection(G.context)) {
                try {
                    Thread threadTask = new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            G.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {

                                        int countSMS = 0;

                                        String smsReceivedSender = "";
                                        String receive_lastID = "";

                                        String r = new JsonService(config_username, config_password, 0, 1, G.F_RECEIVE_SMS).request();
                                        JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(r);

                                        ArrayList<String> items_array = new ArrayList<String>();

                                        JSONObject json_obj = data_array.getJSONObject(0);
                                        receive_lastID = json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms");
                                        smsReceivedSender = json_obj.getString("mobile_number");

                                        for (ReceivedItemStructure rf : items) {
                                            items_array.add(rf.getmLastID());
                                        }

                                        if (items_array.indexOf(receive_lastID) == -1) {
                                            countSMS++;
                                            addDataToList(
                                                    json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms"),
                                                    json_obj.getString("sms_body"),
                                                    json_obj.getString("sms_number"),
                                                    json_obj.getString("mobile_number"),
                                                    json_obj.getString("contact_name"),
                                                    json_obj.getString("recived_date")
                                            );
                                        }


                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    threadTask.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } // END TRY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My custom Adapter code is this:

```
public class ReceivedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReceivedItemStructure> {

    private ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> list;

    public ReceivedAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items) {
        super(c,0,items);
        list = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ReceiveItemView itemView = (ReceiveItemView)convertView;
        if (null == itemView)
            itemView = ReceiveItemView.inflate(parent);

        itemView.setItem(getItem(position));
        return itemView;
    }

    public void update(ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            addAll(items);
        } else {
            for (ReceivedItemStructure item : items) {
                add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`setListAdapter(adapter);` works correctly and I don't have any problem, but after I add new data into `items` **notifyDataSetChanged** it doesn't work.

My manifest content:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is the super class that is handling the dataset, since you are not overriding `getCount` and `getItem`,

```
public void update(ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        addAll(items);
    } else {
       for (ReceivedItemStructure item : items) {
             add(item)
        }
    }
}
```

`addAll`  was introduced with `Honeycomb`, so you probably want to check the current supported sdk where you are app is running

Comment: i get this error : `EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cm.ts.Adapters.Receive.ReceivedAdapter.addAll`

Comment: on what of version of android are you running the application ? And what is the minSdk you are going to support?

Comment: Adapter dont update :( can i upload full code with Adapter to pastebin.com?

Comment: are you sure that addDataToList is called? Btw your thread is kind of wrong since it runs on the UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying your original items collection. But you should to modify adapter's data. Use ArrayAdapter.add method to add new items.